# RStudio, HiddenMarkov Package and dthmm function

Tags: r, function, package, hidden-markov-models

I'm using R version 3.1.0 
and just installed Package `HiddenMarkov`.
Using `library()`, it's confirmed that the package is installed.

I wanted to work thorough `HiddenMarkov`'s [Reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HiddenMarkov/HiddenMarkov.pdf) and tried in-manual examples such as:

Model with class `dthmm` with the Logistic distribution

```
demo("logis", package="HiddenMarkov")
```

After execution of the examples, this error is received:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "dthmm"

Now I wonder how `dthmm` couldn't be found although `HiddenMarkov` library is installed. Any idea to resolve the issue?